# rssi signal strength from existing access points to wifi enabled device e.g. laptop

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to get signal strength readings from existing access points within a given room without having to connect to them. I am very new to android development and eclipse so I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some direction in this matter.
    }

Comment: In other words, write that class for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`
2. Start scanning using `wifiManager.startScan()`
3. In the receiver's `onReceive()`, get the results using [`wifiManager.getScanResults()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29)
4. Loop the result, and get `scanInfo.level`

A similar example can be found [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks). I won't implement that into your class, because you should learn something. If you don't manage to implement your class, you should get yourself more knowledge on Android programming before starting such a project.